# Using undefined references to set counters

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

Consider this example where a number from a previous reference is being
used    to set a counter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{e:one} One
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \setcounter{enumi}{\ref{e:one}}
  \item Next
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

When LaTeX is run for the first time, we get an error about a missing number.

How do we avoid this error?

(My actual scenario of more complex than this where the messages are much more severe.)

**EDIT**

Looks like the actual scenario needs to be elaborated in order to save all
from being misled.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

  \question [10]  \label{e:one} One

\end{questions}

\lipsum[1-5]


\begin{questions}

  \setcounter{question}{\ref{e:one}}
  \question [5] Next

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use `enumitem` which has a `resume` option?

Comment: @cfr Because, as I said, my actual scenario is much more complex where `enumitem` can not be used. Actual counters are not enum or some such.

Comment: In that case, it would help to know a bit more about the context because your current question doesn't make clear that, or why, `enumitem` isn't an option. There are many ways in which things could be more complex: I assumed that the label was being set in the way shown in the question. If it is not, how is it being set?

Comment: You could just use one `questions` environment and escape the indentation. That seems to be supported out-of-the-box. But I've never used this `exam.cls` (only the other `exam.cls`) so this is probably beyond my ken.

Comment: I am an avid user of `exam.cls` and have used that escape many times. But  that does not work under the current scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\setcounterref` from the [`refcount`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcount) package:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{refcount}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question [10]  \label{e:one} One
\end{questions}
\lipsum[1]


\begin{questions}
\question [5] Another
\question [5] Yet another
\setcounterref{question}{e:one}
\question [5] Next
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]